# MongoDB: Query by date

Tags: php, mongodb

In a MongoDB database, I have a collection of items, and each item stores its creation date. I need to query this collection by date. I tried:

> `db.items.findOne({date:{new Date(1285947037*1000)}})`

but it isn't returning anything. I got that timestamp using PHP (`$date->sec`, where `$date` is a `MongoDate` object from the database). So what's the right way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing dates in your collection? Are _they_ unix timestamps, too, or are they stored as Date objects?

Comment: They are stored as Date objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Date` constructor expects a timestamp in **milliseconds**. The `1285947037` timestamp is in **seconds**, which is why you're multiplying it by 1000.

My guess is that the actual timestamp in the document contains milliseconds, e.g. `1285947037461` (note the 461 at the end). You're multiplying the seconds by 1000, which results in `1285947037000`. As you can see, these timestamp aren't equal:

```
1285947037461 // actual timestamp in MongoDB
1285947037000 // value you calculated
```

The problem lies with the `MongoDate` class: it loses the milliseconds precision, as you can read in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php). Here's the quote:

> [...] this means that any precision beyond milliseconds will be lost when the document is sent to/from the database.

To find the document you're looking for using the timestamp in seconds, you need something like this:

```
db.foo.findOne(function () {
  // round the stored date to seconds and compare to timestamp
  return parseInt(this.date / 1000) === 1285947037
})
```

You can get the exact timestamp in milliseconds in the console, by using `myDateObject.getTime()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm having trouble translating this to PHP. Do I have to use MongoCode? Otherwise, what if I store the timestamp in seconds in the document and write the query using that instead?

Comment: @Brainfeeder: MongoCode could work, but I'm not sure, as I don't use PHP myself. Storing the timestamp in seconds would circumvent the problem altogether, so that's also an option.

Answer (score -1):

You have a minor error in your query; remove the curly brackets around `new Date(...)` and you are good to go:

```
db.items.findOne({date: new Date(1285947037*1000)})
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I wrote that line in the post (without copy 'n pasting) and that was a typo.